# Where did they get the bicorn horn from?

Tags: harry-potter, polyjuice-potion

In chapter eleven of *Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets* we are told that one of the ingredients that would need to be procured for the Polyjuice Potion is powdered horn of a bicorn:

> "This is the most complicated potion I've ever seen," said Hermione as they scanned the recipe. "Lacewing flies, leeches, fluxweed, and knotgrass," she murmured, running her finger down the list of ingredients. "Well, they're easy enough, they're in the student store-cupboard, we can help ourselves.... Oooh, look, powdered horn of a bicorn – don't know where we're going to get that – shredded skin of a boomslang – that'll be tricky, too – and of course a bit of whoever we want to change into."

Here Hermione states that she doesn't know how they are going to get the bicorn horn. Later in the same chapter, we are told that both the bicorn horn and the boomslang skin can be stolen from Snape's supplies:

> Unfortunately, the potion was only half finished. They still needed the bicorn horn and the boomslang skin, and the only place they were going to get them was from Snape's private stores.

However, in chapter twenty-seven of *Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire* when Snape accuses Harry of stealing ingredients, he mentions boomslang skin but not bicorn horn:

> "Don't lie to me," Snape hissed, his fathomless black eyes boring into Harry's. "Boomslang skin. Gillyweed. Both come from my private stores, and I know who stole them."

This implies that the bicorn horn did *not* come from Snape's supplies. Moreover, Harry's reaction to Snape's accusation is to recall Hermione stealing the boomslang skin — without any mention of bicorn horn:

> Harry stared back at Snape, determined not to blink or to look guilty. In truth, he hadn't stolen either of these things from Snape. Hermione had taken the boomslang skin back in their second year – they had needed it for the Polyjuice Potion – and while Snape had suspected Harry at the time, he had never been able to prove it. Dobby, of course, had stolen the gillyweed.

Furthermore, in chapter thirty-seven when Barty Crouch Jr. describes stealing the ingredients from Snape, he only mentions boomslang skin:

> The other ingredients were easy. I stole boomslang skin from the dungeons.

And, finally, back in Chapter Eleven of *Chamber of Secrets* Harry discusses the difficulty of stealing from Snape's supplies and again only mentions boomslang skin:

> "D'you realize how much we're going to have to steal, Hermione? Shredded skin of a boomslang, that's definitely not in the students' cupboard. What're we going to do, break into Snape's private stores? I don't know if this is a good idea...."

The implication of these passages is that it was only boomslang skin that needed to be stolen from Snape.

So, was the bicorn horn also stolen from Snape? If not where did they get it from?

Comment: Why isn't it possible that Snape didn't notice the bicorn horn? Or that Barty Crouch Jr. didn't have his own? (-1)

Comment: Or didn't feel like listing every infraction?

Comment: The simplest explanation is that he hasn't inventoried his entire stock. Once he works out what theyre brewing, there really isn't much point

Comment: @Voldemort'sWrath Anything’s possible. An answer would hopefully present arguments as to the reasonableness of any of various possibilities. However, Crouch *not* having his own would make the question stronger. Also, and to address Valorum as well, I would think it likely that Snape would take an inventory once he realized a theft had occurred.

Comment: @Jontia Is it just a coincidence that Snape, Harry, and Crouch all mentioned the boomslang skin and all left out the bicorn horn (though it is possible that Harry would only deal with what Snape mentioned)?

Comment: Possibly. Though you are conflating two different episodes. Crouch may not have had any difficulty getting Bicorn Horn.

Comment: I agree with Jontia. Hermione needed the bicorn horn and stole it from Snape, but Crouch likely had his own supply of horn or was able to get it elsewhere. The recipe states "powdered bicorn horn", but not the quantity, so it might only need a small amount that Crouch was able to furnish himself while the potion requires a much larger amount of boomslang skin. We only get a recipe on Pottermore, I think, and it's vague about quantities but does specify 3 measures of boomslang skin versus 1 measure of bicorn horn.

Comment: “This implies that the bicorn horn did not come from Snape's supplies” No, that’s not how implications work. All we know is that Snape did not mention it. Agreed also that this question is confusing events and consequences. Be careful not to go overboard when trying to read between the lines. Sometimes the cigar is just a cigar. Useful reading: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Everyoneisjesusinpurgatory

Answer (score 4):

In *Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets*, Hermione (with the acquiescence Harry and Ron) stole all the ingredients *they* needed (and could not otherwise obtain) from Snape's store.  That included both the bicorn horn and the boomslang skin.

The fact that Snape does not mention bicorn horn in *Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire* is irrelevant, because he is not talking about the ingredients that children stole at all.  When Snape brings up the missing boomslang skin in *Goblet of Fire*, Harry mistakenly thinks that Snape has finally cottoned onto the fact that the boomslang skin had been stolen, more than a year before.  (The way Snape makes the accusation certainly helps mislead Harry, and potentially the reader.)  In fact, Snape is referring to a much more recent sequence of thefts by Barty Crouch, Jr.  To maintain his disguise as Mad-Eye Moody continuously, Crouch must have needed a much larger quantity of boomslang skin than the trio had used in *Chamber of Secrets*.  Snape had not even noticed Hermione's theft, but Crouch's much larger thefts had not gone similarly undetected.

Since Snape is not talking about the protagonists' theft from the earlier book at all, the fact that he does not mention the bicorn horn tells us nothing about where the the trio got that ingredient.

As to where Crouch got the bicorn horn, we do not know.  However, Crouch (who was a skillful adult wizard, disguised as a distinguished auror) may have simply been able to obtain the horn through normal channels; or he may have been receiving assistance from Voldemort and Pettigrew.  Apparently, it was just easier for him to come by (in the necessary quantities) than the boomslang skin, which he had to steal.

Comment: I had forgotten to include one of the relevant passages in the question, and have since edited it in. That passage is from *Chamber of Secrets* and also only mentions the boomslang skin but not the bicorn horn.

Answer (score 2):

In chapter eleven, while people are taking the Deflating Draft as a consequence of Harry's firework distraction, Harry sees Hermione leaving Snape's private store "[with] the front of her robes bulging".

Afterwards (emphasis mine),

> “He knew it was me,” Harry told Ron and Hermione as they hurried back to Moaning Myrtle’s 
>   bathroom. “I could tell.” **Hermione threw the new ingredients** into the cauldron and began to stir feverishly.
>   “It’ll be ready in two weeks,” she said happily.
>   <sub>*Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets* - Chapter Eleven: *The Dueling Club*</sub>

The text refers to "ingredients" plural. As the quote from your OP says, the only ingredients left for the potion were the boomslang skin and the powdered bicorn horn, so the only new ingredients she could be adding are those which she stole, which *must* have included the powdered bicorn horn. Therefore, to answer your question, **yes**, they did steal the ingredient from Snape.

Admittedly, it is curious that boomslang skin and only boomslang skin is referred to in *Goblet of Fire*. As @Jonita said in a comment, Crouch Jr may have had his own supply of bicorn horn so there was no need to steal from Snape. However the plurality of "ingredients" in *CoS* implies that Hermione definitely stole the powdered bicorn horn from Snape. When Harry says

> Hermione had taken the boomslang skin back in their second year – they had needed it for the Polyjuice Potion
>   <sub>*Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire* - Chapter Twenty Seven: *Padfoot Returns*</sub>

in *GoF*, not mentioning the other ingredient doesn't imply she didn't also steal it. He's just addressing Snape's accusation which pertains only to the boomslang skin. The fact Rowling didn't write

> Hermione had taken the boomslang skin back in their second year, not to mention powdered bicorn horn – they had needed it for the Polyjuice Potion
>   <sub>A reimagining of *Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire* - Chapter Twenty Seven: *Padfoot Returns*</sub>

doesn't mean Hermione didn't steal it. If anything, Harry may not recall her stealing another ingredient.

Comment: Note that the plural "ingredients" is also used by Barty Crouch, which would presumably mean that contrary to the comments and answer above, he also stole bicorn horn from Snape.

Comment: @Alex It still doesn't necessarily preclude him having his own bicorn horn supply... I don't recall how it was said exactly in the book but he may have had to steal boomslang skin from Snape's private supply, but other ingredients could have been stolen from the student store-cupboard. So he has indeed stolen ingredient**s** but maybe only one specifically from Snape?

Comment: @JonClements *Potter saw me stealing more ingredients for the Polyjuice Potion from Snape's office one night.*

Comment: @Alex ahhh... in that case then, that makes it more likely he was stealing bicorn horn from Snape and it just wasn't noticed... it'd make no sense to steal from Snape unless he needed to if everything else was available in the student cupboards...?

Comment: @JonClements It presumably wasn't availablein the student cupboards, as in the same breath as mentioning taking other ingredients from the cupboards Hermione stated that she doesn't know where they'll get bicorn horn from.

Comment: @Alex Crouch Jr says "The other ingredients were easy. I stole boomslang skin from the dungeons." If I was to say "Buying the shopping was easy. I got bread from the bakers." I'm not implying I got all of my shopping from the bakers, just in particular I got the bread from there. I think Crouch is just bragging about his complete infiltration of Hogwarts tbh. Whether he got the bicorn horn from Snape or not is irrelevant though - your question concerns where the trio got it from in *CoS* and I believe I've answered that.

Comment: @Ongo There are two different quotes from Crouch. In addition to what you just cited, he also said *Potter saw me stealing more ingredients for the Polyjuice Potion from Snape's office one night.* which pretty explicitly says that ingredient**s** were stolen from Snape.

Comment: @Alex Like I say though, your question is about where the trio got the bicorn horn from in *CoS*, and I think the text makes it pretty clear it came from the private stores. The potion absolutely needs powdered bicorn horn, and Hermione says their only source would be Snape's store. Immediately after raiding said store she adds the final ingredient**s** to the Polyjuice. Had they sourced it elsewhere, I'm sure at least a throwaway explanation would have been included (Ron asks a brother to send some via owl for example) if not a whole other adventure similar to the raiding of the store.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96769/discussion-on-answer-by-ongo-where-did-they-get-the-bicorn-horn-from).